# Find Value of Array Key Before Foreach Statement (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-4

My problem here is that I need to get the key of a particular value before beginning a foreach loop. **In the first line of the code**, you see that I have just put $categories[] in as a placeholder. I can't start my foreach loop until after I declare the form. Otherwise I am going to get a new form every time.

This is a form that shows all income categories in a table. If a user chooses to edit a category, the page reloads with a text box and a "Save" and "Cancel" button on just that category. The parameter in the first line must be included or else Laravel does not know which record to update.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=> array('income-category.update', $categories[]), 'method'=>'PUT')) }}
          @foreach($categories as $catId=>$catVal)
            @if($_GET['category'] == $catId)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ Form::text('category_name', $catVal) }} <br>{{ $errors->first('category_name') }}</td>
                <td>
                  {{ Form::submit('Save', ['category'=>$catId, 'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm', 'title'=>'Save']) }}&nbsp;
                  {{ link_to('income-category', 'Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-sm', 'title'=>'Cancel']) }}
                </td>
              </tr>
            @else
              <tr id="{{ 'item_'. $i }}">  
                <td>{{ $catVal }}</td>
                <td>{{ HTML::linkAction('IncomeCategoryController@index', '', ['category'=>$catId], ['class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil shadow pointer', 'title'=>'Edit']) }}&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ Form::button('', ['category'=>$catId, 'type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-trash shadow pointer', 'title'=>'Delete', 'onclick' => 'confirm("For now this is just going to delete no matter what you pick.")']) }} </td>
              </tr>
            @endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: I don't think a form is the right way to go here.  I would just have a list of links which points to `/income-category/update/$id` and then that would be a form.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but did you try `array_keys()` for all keys and `key()` for a particular array item's key and `current()` as well?

Comment: Take care of as much logic as possible in your controller.  Do your looping and find the key you are looking for there, then pass it to your view.  Also, use `Request::query('category')` instead of referencing a super global directly.

Comment: You don't need any loops. When you reload the form, that means you executed another request, so you have needed key already (in `POST` or `GET`, depending on the way you reload it). Or, if you do it with JS/AJAX, then simply alter form's `action` with JS accordingly.